# What is the "Replace" object that pops up when I select text in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I can't find a screenshot anywhere - but essentially, when I select text from an `EditText` on Android (4.0+, I think), a small white bubble saying `REPLACE` pops up, to allow me to replace the text with other predictions. The same kind of bubble pops up saying `PASTE` when I long press a field. What class is this? I can't seem to find any reference to it in the developer docs; could somebody help me out?

If it's just a custom view, where is it instantiated? I'd like to write an Xposed module that requires this method, but I'm damned if I can find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to get rid of this one?

[image: Text selection handle with paste menu]

The PASTE/REPLACE menu code is in the [`show()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/Editor.java#Editor.ActionPopupWindow.show%28%29) method of the (non-documented) `android.widget.Editor` class:

```
    public void show() {
        boolean canPaste = mTextView.canPaste();
        boolean canSuggest = mTextView.isSuggestionsEnabled() && isCursorInsideSuggestionSpan();
        mPasteTextView.setVisibility(canPaste ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mReplaceTextView.setVisibility(canSuggest ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

        if (!canPaste && !canSuggest) return;

        super.show();
    }
```

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28893714/3063884