# How to disable longtouch, copy and past and cursor when the screen is rotated on Android?

Tags: android

I tried everything that I could to remove the copy and past, long touch and the blue selectors.

I followed the all suggestion on this thread:

[EditText: Disable Paste/Replace menu pop-up on Text Selection Handler click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869983/edittext-disable-paste-replace-menu-pop-up-on-text-selection-handler-click-even/28893714#28893714)

However, it only works when my phone screen is in portraid mode.. if I rotate the screen in landscape mode then I still see the text selections, long press, etc.. I wanna rid of these blue cursors and copy and past functionality.

I notice in landscape, the onTouch methods are not called.. seems to be an independent object and does not respect the layout and class definitions.

Any idea is very welcome.
[image]

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869983/edittext-disable-paste-replace-menu-pop-up-on-text-selection-handler-click-even).

Comment: Surender Kumar thank you ! but this thread only works when the device is in portrait mode.. in landscape does not.