# Android selecting text on TextView/EditText without having ContextMenu

Tags: android

as we know in `TextView` or `EditText` after selecting text we have `ContextMenu`, my question is: how can i select text without having `ContextMenu` or disable showing that?

this code work, but that cause of can't selecting text

```
public class MyEditText extends AppCompatEditText {
    private final Context mContext;
    private       int     mPreviousCursorPosition;

    public MyEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
        CharSequence text = getText();
        if (text != null) {
            if (selStart != selEnd) {
                setSelection(selStart, selEnd);
                return;
            }
        }
        mPreviousCursorPosition = selStart;
        super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For API level 11 or above do this:

```
edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        }

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            //This will prevent opening the menu
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Further readings:

- [How to disable copy/paste from/to EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext)
- [How to disable "copy/cut/paste/" toolbar in editText, but still have cursor to select some text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093900/how-to-disable-copy-cut-paste-toolbar-in-edittext-but-still-have-cursor-to-s)
- [EditText: Disable Paste/Replace menu pop-up on Text Selection Handler click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869983/edittext-disable-paste-replace-menu-pop-up-on-text-selection-handler-click-even)