# How to apply overrided class on EditText

Tags: android, kotlin

I found some code in stackoverflow and I want to use that code in my app.
I have already overrided the EditText class(NoMenuEditText) like it is via link below.
The question is what should I do now with that overrided class?
I have EditText with id EditTextUserTask, how can I apply NoMenuEditText (overrided class) to EditTextUserTask inside my MainActivity?

[EditText: Disable Paste/Replace menu pop-up on Text Selection Handler click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869983/edittext-disable-paste-replace-menu-pop-up-on-text-selection-handler-click-even/28893714#28893714)

I accept Java and Kotlin answers but if you can provide an answer in Kotlin, it would be better, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is what should I do now with that overrided class?

Just use your custom view in your layout.

```
<yourPackage.NoMenuEditText
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="......"
   android:id="@+id/editTextUserTask"
  />
```

In your `MainActivity` just

```
   NoMenuEditText ed = findViewById(R.id.editTextUserTask)
```