# Disable copy/past in Android app with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to de-activate all copy/paste operations from my EditText. The `setLongClickable(false)` alone is not working. Please Help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869983/edittext-disable-paste-replace-menu-pop-up-on-text-selection-handler-click-even/28893714#28893714  check the solution give here.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this post

Comment: If any answer or comment helped you, pls consider upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting it via `ActionMode` as well, like so:

```
textField.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
    }
});

textField.setLongClickable(false);
textField.setTextIsSelectable(false);
```

Comment: this will not prevent "paste" option.

Answer (score 0):

Along with setLongClicable(false), add the below code

```
mEditText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        }

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

If you need this functionality at multiple places, You can create an extension with above code and call it on edittext

Answer (score 0):

So, I found an non complete answer to my question, I will be following those steps :

1 - extend a custom class from EditText or TextInputEditText

`

```
open class CustomEditText : TextInputEditText {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {
        disableCopyPastMenu()
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        disableCopyPastMenu()
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        disableCopyPastMenu()
    }
}
```

`
2- in your layout use replace your edittext with customEditText

```
`<xxxx.CustomEditText
       android:id="xxxxxx"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="xxx"
       android:inputType="xx" />`
```

3- add a method to `disableMenu()` where we can find copy and past

`private fun disableCopyPastMenu() {
        this.customSelectionActionModeCallback = object : ActionMode.Callback {
            override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
                return false
            }

```
        override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode, item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode) {}
    }
    this.isLongClickable = false
    this.isClickable = false
    this.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        clearFocus()
        return@setOnTouchListener false
    }
}`
```

4 - override onTouchEvent() with a method to disable insertion

`

```
 override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            disableInsertion()
        } return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    private fun disableInsertion() {
        try {
            val editorField = TextView::class.java.getDeclaredField("))
                    editorField . isAccessible = true
                    val editorObject = editorField [this]
            val editorClass = Class.forName(")
                    val insertionControllerEnabled = editorClass . getDeclaredField (")
                    insertionControllerEnabled . isAccessible = true
            insertionControllerEnabled[editorObject] = false
        } catch (exception: Exception) { // add exception if needed
        }
    }
```

`
5- override isSuggedtionsEnabled() making it return false

`

```
override fun isSuggestionsEnabled(): Boolean {
        return false
    }
```

`

this code works well, except sometimes the copy past menu is showing i don't know why!!!

also I'd like to unit tests this CustumEditText, any guess's to start with.

Answer (score 0):

```
val pasteFilter = InputFilter { source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend -> if (source.length == 1 && source[0] != '\n') null}
edittext.filters = arrayOf(pasteFilter)
edittext.customSelectionActionModeCallback = object : ActionMode.Callback {
    override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?) = false
    override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?) = false
    override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {}
    override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): = false
}
edittext.isLongClickable = false
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).